# Get the page ID from a page with shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I get the page ID from a page which has shortcode.
I have tried this but unable to get it with different methods I tried.

Here is the code

```
function pro_availabiltyid() {
    global $pro_templateid;

    $pro_wp_query= new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
        )
    );
    if ( $pro_wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $pro_wp_query->have_posts() ) {
            $pro_wp_query->the_post();
            $post_content = get_the_content();
            if ( has_shortcode( $post_content, 'availability' ) ) {
                $pro_templateid = get_the_ID();
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'pro_availabiltyid' );

var_dump( $pro_templateid );
```

Page content

```
Lorem Ipsum
[availability]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your goal here? It's VERY inefficient to get all posts from mysql on every request.

Comment: I agree with your point. Will have to find alternative method then.

Comment: please share the shortcode you have in the page

Comment: Edit the post added the page content

Answer (score 0):

Try [get_shortcode_regex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex)

add code in `functions.php` in active theme folder

```
function detect_my_shortcode()
{
    global $post,$pro_templateid;
    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

    if (   preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches )
        && array_key_exists( 2, $matches )
        && in_array( 'availability', $matches[2] ) )  //YOUR SHORTCODE
    {
        // shortcode is being used
        $pro_templateid = $post->ID;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'detect_my_shortcode' );
```